# Visualization data train and data test from train_test_split with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've a data which has row 9583 and I split it with `train_test_split`. I want to visualization my data train and data test using barplot like this example:

[image: example barplot]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Data/data_clean_spacy_for_implementation.xlsx")

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df["text"], df["label"], test_size=0.2, stratify=df["label"], random_state=42)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
X_array = X_train.toarray()

print(X_train.shape) #output (7666, 12222)
print(X_test.shape) #output (1917, 12222)
```

How to do that?

My data [github](https://github.com/k4waiiiii/sentimen-analisis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to count unique values of each label, follow by [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) using the `index` as x-axis and `values` as the y-axis. If it makes any sense for your analysis, you can use `sharey='row'` (`plt.subplots(..., sharey='row')`) so each row (both columns, `train` and `test`) will share the same y-axis.

```py
...
...
print(X_train.shape) #output (7666, 12222)
print(X_test.shape) #output (1917, 12222)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,5))
for idx, group in enumerate([('Train', y_train), ('Test', y_test)]):
    data = group[1].value_counts()
    sns.barplot(ax=ax[idx], x=data.index, y=data.values)
    ax[idx].set_title(f'{group[0]} Label Count')
    ax[idx].set_xlabel(f'{group[0]} Labels')
    ax[idx].set_ylabel('Label Count')

plt.show()
```

[image: train_test_label_count]